# finding largest subset of intervals

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I was trying to solve this problem [here](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4fbcda3baf3e5).

Also, posting the question: You are given a list of N intervals.
The challenge is to select the largest subset of intervals such that no three intervals in the subset share a common point?

but couldn't come around to a solution. This is what I tried so far:

1. DP: don't think problem has overlapping sub-problems so this didn't work
2. reduced it to a graph with each point being a vertex and intervals being the edges of the undirected graph.  Then problem reduces to finding maximum length disjoint paths in the graph. Couldn't come up with a neat way of doing this as well
3. tried reducing it to network flow but that didn't work as well.

Could you guys give me hints on how to approach this problem or if I am missing anything. Sorry, I am doing algorithms after a really long time and been out of touch lately.

Comment: Sounds like a job for an segment tree.

Comment: This sounds like a scheduling problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give the solution in general words without programming it.

Let's denote segments as s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>, ..., s<sub>n</sub>. Their beginnings as b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>,... b<sub>n</sub>, and their ends as e<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>2</sub>,... e<sub>n</sub>.

Sort segments by their beginnings, so b<sub>1</sub>< b<sub>2</sub><...< b<sub>n</sub>. It is enough to check them if the condition of no three segments covering a point holds. We will be doing so in the order from b<sub>1</sub> to b<sub>n</sub>. So, start with b<sub>1</sub>, move to the next point, and so on one by one, until at some point b<sub>i</sub> there are three segments covering it. These will be the segment s<sub>i</sub> and two others, let's say s<sub>j</sub> and s<sub>k</sub>. Of those three segments delete the one with the maximum end point, i.e. max{e<sub>i</sub>, e<sub>j</sub>, e<sub>k</sub>}. Move on to the beginning of the next segment (b<sub>i+1</sub>). When we reach b<sub>n</sub> the process is done. All the segments that are left constitute the largest subset of segments such that no three segments  share a common point.

Why this will be the maximal subset. Let's say our solution is S (the set of segments). Suppose there is an optimal solution S*. Again, sort the segments in S and S* by the coordinate of their beginnings. Now, we will be going through the segments in S and in S* and comparing their end points. By the construction of S for any k<sup>th</sup> segment in S its end coordinate is smaller than the end coordinate of k<sup>th</sup> segment in S* (e<sub>k</sub><=e<sub>k</sub>*). Therefore, the number of segments in S is not less than in S* (moving in S* we're always outrunning S).

If this is not convincing enough, try to think about a simpler problem at first, where no two segments can overlap. The solution is the same, but it's much more intuitive to see why it gives the right answer.

Comment: ok, correct me if i am wrong but lets say if I have these segments (1-2),(1-3),(1-10),(3-5),(3-6), then according to this algorithm the solution should be (1-2),(1-3),(3-5) but a better solution could be (1-10),(1-2),(3-5)(3-6)

Comment: @user352951 in your example (1-10), (3-5) and (3-6) overlap

Answer (score 2):

Shafa is Right;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Interval{
public:
int begin;int end;
Interval(){
    begin=0;end=0;
}

Interval(int _b,int _e){
    begin=_b;end=_e;
}

 bool operator==(const Interval& i) const {
     return (begin==i.begin)&&(end==i.end);
 }

 bool operator<(const Interval& i) const {
     return begin<i.begin;
 }
};

int n,t,a,b;
multiset<Interval> inters;
multiset<int> iends;

multiset<Interval>::iterator it1;
multiset<int>::iterator et1;

int main(){
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--){
    inters.clear();
    iends.clear();
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--){
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        Interval inter(a,b);
        inters.insert(inter);
    }
    it1=inters.begin();
    while(it1!=inters.end()){
        iends.insert(it1->end);
        et1=iends.lower_bound(it1->begin);
        multiset<int>::iterator t=et1;
        if((++et1!=iends.end())&&(++et1!=iends.end())){
            //æŠŠå‰©ä¸‹çš„çº¿æ®µå…¨éƒ¨åˆ æŽ‰
            while(et1!=iends.end()){
                multiset<int>::iterator te=et1;
                et1++;
                iends.erase(te);
            }
        }
        it1++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",iends.size());
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```